# Which applications use /usr/share/dict/words

Tags: dictionary

I have changed the symlink `/usr/share/dict/words` to point to my own custom dictionary but it doesn't seem to affect anything.

Chromium and Abiword neither seem to use this dictionary.

Which appilications use `words`? Do I have to manually configure each application to use it? What is the point of having a system dictionary if applications are going to use their own anyway?

Comment: Look for packages depending on that file/the package containing it... my (not minimal, but not full either) shows no installed packages depending on it.

Comment: For Arch linux, no packages seem to depend on /usr/share/dict/words, which constitutes its own package, "community/words".  pacman -Q -i words seems to indicate that GNU aspell uses it, but there's no package dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two come to mind: both **`look`** from `util-linux`(`man look` and read description) and **`ispell`** (for the lookup) use that file. Most likely it has also other uses that I'm not aware of.

As to your other question (Chromium, Abiword etc)... Most distros nowadays use a wrapper lib called [`enchant`](http://www.abisource.com/projects/enchant/) for spell checking. `enchant` supports up to 8 back-ends that actually do the spell-check job (see home project page), [`hunspell`](http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/) (forked from `myspell`) and [`aspell`](http://aspell.net/) being the most popular. You'll have to look into the particulars of your distro and get familiar with `enchant` and its backend(s)...